# $W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$ is dense in $L^2(\Lambda)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Let

- $d\in\mathbb N$
- $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R^d$
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be open with $\lambda(\Lambda)<\infty$
- $p\ge 2$
- $W^1(\Lambda)$ denote the set of weakly differentiable functions $\Lambda\to\mathbb R$, $$W^{1,\:p}(\Lambda):=\left\{u\in W^1(\Lambda)\cap L^p(\Lambda):\nabla u\in L^p(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)\right\}$$ be equipped with $$\left\|u\right\|_{W^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)}:=\left(\left\|u\right\|_{L^p(\Lambda)}+\left\|\nabla u\right\|_{L^p(\Lambda,\:\mathbb R^d)}\right)^{\frac 1p}\;\;\;\text{for }u\in W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$$ and \begin{equation}
  \begin{split}
  W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)&:=\left\{u\in W^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)\mid\exists(\varphi_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq C_c^\infty(\Lambda):\left\|\varphi_n-u\right\|_{W^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)}\stackrel{n\to\infty}\to 0\right\}\\
  &=\overline{C_c^\infty(\Lambda)}^{\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{W_0^{1,\:p}}}
  \end{split}
  \end{equation}

> I'm trying to understand why
>
> 1. $W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$ is dense in $L^2(\Lambda)$
> 2. On $W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$, the $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{W^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)}$-topology $\tau_1$ is [finer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies#Definition) than the $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda)}$-topology $\tau_2$

Since $\lambda(\Lambda)<\infty$, it's obvious that $C_c^\infty(\Lambda)\subseteq L^p(\Lambda)$. Thus, since $C_c^\infty(\Lambda)$ is dense in $L^2(\Lambda)$, it's clear that $L^p(\Lambda)$ is dense in $L^2(\Lambda)$, if I'm not terribly wrong.

However, I don't know how we can conclude (1.) and (2.). So, how can we prove these statements?

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of $W_0^{1,p}$, because I don't see anything related to $0$ in that definition.

Comment: $C_c^\infty\subset W^{1,p}_0$ and $C_c^\infty$ is dense in $L^q$ for any $1\leq q<\infty$.

Comment: @Bowditch Yeah, you're right. (1.) basically follows by the same argumentation that I've mentioned in the question. Do you know an answer to (2.)? Since $\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{L^2(\Lambda)}\le\left\|\;\cdot\;\right\|_{W^{1,\:p}( \Lambda)}$, shouldn't $\tau_1$ be coarser than $\tau_2$? The question arose, cause I've seen that people consider $W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)\subset L^2(\Lambda)\subset W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)'$ as a [Gelfand triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigged_Hilbert_space) and, if I don't get anything wrong, that would require (2.).

Comment: @TrialAndError Of course not. I've actually defined $W^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$. Just tried to simplify things and failed in doing that.

Comment: @0xbadf00d if $\|\cdot\|_A\leq \|\cdot\|_B$ then $x_n\to x$ in $B\implies x_n\to x$ in $A$ (but not vice versa) hence $B$ has more open sets that $A$ so $B$ is finer than $A$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: An open set can have a very pathological boundary. I'm not sure that what you have stated is necessarily true. Have you omitted assumptions?

Comment: @TrialAndError Maybe. I'm just trying to understand an example of a Gelfand tripel in a book that I'm reading and all they assume is that $\Lambda$ is open with $\lambda(\Lambda)<\infty$.

Comment: @Bowditch Yes, that answers my question. Since I thought about $W_0^{1,\:p}(\Lambda)$ being more restrictive than $L^2(\Lambda)$, it seemed a bit confusing to me that $\tau_1$ is finer than $\tau_2$.